# Windows Batch - Call Cygwin to Execute TCL Expect Script

Tags: bash, batch-file, tcl, expect

I'm attempting to use Cygwin from a Windows server to automate some commands that need to be run on a remote Linux server. To solve this issue I've built an expect script that runs within Cygwin to SSH to the Linux server and execute the appropriate commands.

Now I'm trying to take that automation one step further by wrapping the execution of Cygwin with a batch script and schedule it via the Windows Task scheduler.

I've tried the following to call Bash from my batch script:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash C:\myscript.exp
```

This causes the script to throw an error when the TCL Expect language syntax appears.

I've also tried the following to call Expect from my batch script:

```
 c:\cygwin64\bin\expect C:\myscript.exp
```

This causes the script to throw an error when I try to spawn SSH

Here is a snippet from my Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
proc doSomething {p1 p2} {

    expect "* information here:"
    send -- "$p1\r" 
}
set server [lrange $argv 0 0]

spawn ssh perfmet@$server
# Additional commands below
```

Is there any way for me to get this solution working?

Edit:

Here are the error messages when I use the Bash executable to launch the script:

```
C:\scpbot_reset>scpbot_reset.bat
C:\cygwin64\home\myaccountr\scpbot_reset\reset_script: line 2: proc: command not fo
und
C:\cygwin64\home\myaccountr\scpbot_reset\reset_script: line 3: expect: command not
found
C:\cygwin64\home\myaccountr\scpbot_reset\reset_script: line 4: send: command not fo
und
```

Here is the error message when I use the Expect executable to launch the script:

```
C:\scpbot_reset>scpbot_reset.bat
couldn't execute "ssh": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn ssh perfmet@192.168.0.199"
    (file "C:\cygwin64\home\myaccountr\scpbot_reset\reset_script" line 14)
```

Comment: Can you provide the error when you try to spawn SSH?

Comment: @tomdemuyt I have added the error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a true expect script *cannot* be executed by bash. Some people write code that is mixed between bash and expect — that's very Unix-ish, so much so that I'd expect even cygwin to have problems with it — but you're strongly advised to not do.

Fortunately, your script is indeed a true expect script. It should therefore be invoked from the cygwin shell as:

```
expect myscript.exp
```

Plus whatever paths are necessary.

The reason it fails when you do that is that ssh (possibly ssh.exe) is either not installed at all, or is not present on your PATH. Fix that by installing it or correcting your PATH; you can probably figure out which you need to do far more quickly than I can describe all the possibilities. (I personally prefer to use plink.exe from the PuTTY suite of programs when I need a scriptable SSH implementation on Windows, but that's entirely up to you.)

Comment: FWIW, that second error message looks “right”; expect is functioning correctly there, it just can't do what you _want_ it to do due to circumstances beyond its control.

Comment: That was exactly it.  A co-worker just came by and suggested pointing the spawn statement to the direct path to SSH.  Everything seems to be working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "expect /cygdrive/C/myscript.exp"
```

Comment: BTW, `lrange` returns a list, `lindex` returns an element of a list. Use `lindex $argv 0`

Comment: That throws the following error:
/usr/bin/bash: expect: command not found

I will replace lrange with lindex.
I'm looking into calling the mintty.exe executable with a parameter to mimic my desktop shortcut behaviour.

Comment: inside cygwin, where is expect installed?